# How to translate a route scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, routes

I'm trying to translate the routes in a Rails application. I tried with `i18n_routes`, but I had some problems with translating actions that didn't depend on a resource. In the end, I solved it without using i18n_routes, as explained [**here**](https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing/issues/30).

The issue now is that I don't find the way to translate scopes. This is my `routes.rb`:

```
scope "sport" do
  translated_named_route 'it_is_healthy', 'sport#it_is_healthy'
  translated_named_route 'it_is_social', 'sport#it_is_social'
end
```

How to translate sport? I tried with `i18n_routes` again, but I don't see how to translate the scope. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, if you're not using i18n_routes then why do you still have a `localized` in there? Isn't that part of i18n_routes?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just tried to use i18n_routes again, and tested with all the yml keys they offer, but it didn't work. Maybe I should avoid the reference to i18n_routes.

Comment: Yes that makes it easier to understand, thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty tough problem, I don't think it can be fixed with just a line or two. I'd like to help but without looking in detail at `i18n_routes` I don't think I'd know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a gem for this, I would recommend using

https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes

The readme is fairly comprehensive and it definitely covers namespaces and scopes in the routes as well.